# La función se ejecuta solo una vez PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados soy nuevo en esto y estoy practicando funciones en php, hice una función que recibe como parámetro el id de usuario y debe devolverme el nombre.

Cuando la llamo una vez me trae todo ok, pero al volver a llamarla en la misma pagina no me vuelve a traer nada.
Alguien me sabe explicar porque?

Gracias.

> Funciones.php

```
function Horarios($id){

    include('conexion.php');
    $sql= $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM horarios 
    WHERE numero='$id' AND tipo='ORIGINAL' ORDER BY linea DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        return 'Horaios -> '.$id.' '.$row['nombre'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

> index.php

```
require("funciones.php");

echo Horarios(7899);
echo Horarios(9988);
```

Comment: ¿Existe un usuario con id `9988` en la BD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código no está **optimizado**: no tiene sentido incluir la conexión cada vez, no es **seguro**: deberías usar consultas preparadas, de lo contrario te expones a un grave riesgo de seguridad y no controla posibles **errores en la lógica**: en algunos casos puede no haber resultados en la consulta (el criterio no se cumple).

Te propongo lo siguiente:

#### `funciones.php`

```
# Una función desde la cual llames a la conexión
# Cuando estés más avanzado será más simple con una Clase

function getConnection() {
    include_once('conexion.php');
    return $conexion;
}

function Horarios($id){
    $conexion=getConnection();
    $stmt= $conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM horarios 
    WHERE numero=? AND tipo='ORIGINAL' ORDER BY linea DESC LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        $stmt->bind_result($nombre);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return sprintf('Horarios -> %s es %s',$id,$nombre);
    } else {
        return 'No se encontraron filas';
    }
}
```

#### `index.php`

```
require("funciones.php");

echo Horarios(7899);
echo Horarios(9988);
```

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por tus comentarios! pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo, solo me muestra los datos la primer vez que llamo a la función.

Comment: @Sebastian ¿la segunda vez no muestra nada? He programado el código para que si un usuario no existe te muestre el mensaje:  `No se encontraron filas`. Revisa también la respuesta editada, he puesto una función para obtener la conexión. De todos modos, si piensas usar mucho la conexión a la base de datos, lo mejor será crear una clase envoltorio y manejar la conexión con dicha clase. Si sigue sin funcionar, muestra los errores en tu archivo temporalmente y dinos qué errores ves en pantalla.

Comment: @Sebastian para mostrar los errores agrega **temporalmente** estas tres líneas en `index.php`, **al inicio**: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` así verás si hay algún error en tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, el problema es que redeclare la variable conexión dado que ya existía en mi archivo conexión.php.